# SQL 2008 R2 - Time-Based Triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to have a stored procedure or set of SQL code run periodically by specifying a time-based trigger in SQL Server?

Comment: Can't you use a SQL Job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly, but look at [SQL Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx).

> A job is a specified series of operations performed sequentially by SQL Server Agent. A job can perform a wide range of activities, including running Transact-SQL scripts, command-line applications, Microsoft ActiveX scripts, Integration Services packages, Analysis Services commands and queries, or Replication tasks. **Jobs can run repetitive tasks or those that can be scheduled**, and they can automatically notify users of job status by generating alerts, thereby greatly simplifying SQL Server administration.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [SQL Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) job. IF you have a requirement to run on Express editions, that lack SQL Agent, you can use [dialog timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) and [activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171601.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL job to run any SQL on a schedule. If you are needing to do something a little more dynamic you can control the jobs (creation, scheduling, removing etc) from SQL itself. This provides an immense amount of flexibility.

Some more info on controlling jobs with TSQL [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/managingjobsusingtsql/945/).