# Sql Server: Modify field at a specific date which is stored in same table row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table :

```
StartDate | EndDate | Value | Active  - and some other columns
```

I want to automatically set `Active` to false if `EndDate` is less then today.

Is there any way i could do that ? I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2.

What i mean by automatically is this:

End date is 14 sep 2013,and as soon as the clock hits 00:00 and today is 15 sep i want to flag that row as inactive - false.

Comment: Automatically as in as soon as the date changes or you log in on SQL server or as in running a query?

Comment: Do you mean if `EndDate` is before today?

Comment: Try looking into [those documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx) and [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5573002/1578604).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a one off `update` to run now, then you can use this...

```
UPDATE  tblName
SET     Active = 'False'
WHERE   CAST(EndDate AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND (Active = 'True' OR Active IS NULL)
```

If it's `EndDate` **before** today...

```
UPDATE  tblName
SET     Active = 'False'
WHERE   CAST(EndDate AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND (Active = 'True' OR Active IS NULL)
```

If this is not what you're looking for, add more specific information to the question and I will update the answer.

As for calling this automatically, you could either set up a [SQL server job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx) or have a [windows service](http://milindapro.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/create-window-service-project-in-c-part_16.html) that calls a stored procedure on a timer.

Comment: @gMailMan, I have updated this (3rd query) to update all records where the `EndDate` has expired...i.e., if you run it now, all records with `EndDate` of 13th or before will be set to false.

Comment: Yes,SQL server job are what i was looking for.Thanks.

Comment: Strange this got accepted as the 'winning' answer as the solution below using computed columns is by far superior to it.

Comment: @deroby, **"Thats a smart solution,but it wont work for me,because user can chose which,out of many,states is active"**, so I guess it depends how the OP wants to use the solutions on offer.

Comment: Appologies, I hadn't read the comment on the view-solution (which I think is 2nd-best). Anyway, if it seemingly doesn't work then I'd suggest to extend the computed column and include all states. The only alternative is having a way to update the field each time some 'relevant information' changes (here: the clock). IMHO you'll probably have to choose between either putting triggers all over the place (and a job that runs each midnight) or accept having stale data. The only reason to live with the latter is because the computation would be that complex that it can't be done in 'real-time'.

Comment: This solution could be optimized if you add following predicate: `WHERE ... AND (Active = 'True' OR Active IS NULL)`. `Active IS NULL` is needed only if `Active` allows NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're looking for it to be 'automatic'... Why not use a view... i.e.:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTest]
AS
    SELECT  [StartDate] ,
            [EndDate] ,
            [Value] ,
            CAST(CASE WHEN loaddate > GETDATE() THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                 END AS BIT) AS Active
    FROM    TestTable
```

And in this way you can work on the view which will automatically always have the correct value in the 'derived field' of Active...

Cheers, 
Noah

Comment: Thats a smart solution,but it wont work for me,because user can chose which,out of many,states is active