# Automatic update of values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auto-update

For example I have a table `tb` with columns :

```
order_id | date_ordered | due_date | status
```

Are there any out of the box solution where I can automatically update `status` column when the current time (from server) reaches the value of the `due_date` column? How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

Something like this :

```
test1 | 2016-03-30 09:19:06.610 | 2016-03-30 11:19:06.610 | NEW
test2 | 2016-03-30 09:22:43.513 | 2016-03-30 11:22:43.513 | NEW
test3 | 2016-03-30 09:06:03.627 | 2016-03-30 11:06:03.627 | NEW
```

When the server time reaches `2016-03-30 11:19:06.610`, `test1`'s status will change value say, `overdue`

Comment: Use a sql server job, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190268.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573002/sql-2008-r2-time-based-triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "out of the box solution". You could create a sql server agent job, which checks every minute if the value due_date is less or equal to the current date and time and change the state column.

A computed column might be another, much simpler solution.

A table like this might suffice:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_test (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    date_ordered  DATETIME,
    due_date DATETIME,
    [status] as 
    CASE WHEN due_date <= GETDATE() THEN 'overdue'
    ELSE 'new' END
 );
```

Comment: The are many good tutorials on creating a sql server agent job. I think this is well beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer.

Comment: Here are the Microsoft [docs on creating a job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190268.aspx).  There are also numerous blog posts that include examples.  A quick [google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20create%20a%20sql%20server%20agent%20job) should return a few.